# Organize a map of items

Tags: go, slack

I am working on a Slack bot to calculate the most active people in the channel, what I need to do is create some type of a map/dictionary with their user id as the key and then the value of the count of messages they sent in the channel.

My idea was to build the map of all the users with the count of each users messages and then find a way to sort them, since Maps do not guarantee ordering I cant use that, but what would the alternative be? I thought about sorting it and then putting the values in an Array (My understanding is arrays are ordered) and then that would give me the ordering and I can query the map for the number of items, but this seems inefficient.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: If the data should exist across multiple invocations of the program, Redis would be an excellent choice to store ranked values.